# GLSL Bump mapping looking flat

Tags: opengl, glsl

I need to get something like:

*the close up*

[image]

*zoomed out*

[image]

So far, I have something like:

[image]

**[Fragment shader (full source)](http://pastebin.com/CwR0keEL)**

**[Vector shader (full source)](http://pastebin.com/XkyC4aAj)**

The most obvious problem is the bump map ... its flat, why is that? The "relavent" code (in my opinion):

```
vec2 c = TileDensity * gl_TexCoord[0].st;
vec2 p = fract( c ) - vec2( 0.5 );

// Some useful eye-space vectors.
vec3 ecNNormal = normalize( ecNormal );
vec3 ecViewVec = -normalize( ecPosition );

vec3 N = ecNNormal;
vec3 B = normalize( cross( N, ecTangent ) );
vec3 T = cross( B, N );

vec3 tanPerturbedNormal;  // The perturbed normal vector in tangent space of fragment.
vec3 ecPerturbedNormal;   // The perturbed normal vector in eye space.
vec3 ecReflectVec;        // The mirror reflection vector in eye space.

...

vec3 lightPos = vec3( gl_LightSource[0].position ) / gl_LightSource[0].position.w;
vec3 lightVec = normalize( lightPos - ecPosition );
vec3 halfVector = normalize( lightVec + ecViewVec );

...

if (fractionalPart.s < TubeRadius
    || fractionalPart.s > 1-TubeRadius
    || fractionalPart.t < TubeRadius
    || fractionalPart.t > 1-TubeRadius) {

    vec3 i = normalize(ecPosition);
    vec3 n = normalize(vec3(p.x, p.y, 1.0));

    tanPerturbedNormal.x = dot(T, n); 
    tanPerturbedNormal.y = dot(B, n);
    tanPerturbedNormal.z = dot(N, n);

    ecPerturbedNormal = n;

    vec3 tanLightPos;
    tanLightPos.x = dot(T, lightPos); // LightDir?
    tanLightPos.y = dot(B, lightPos);
    tanLightPos.z = dot(N, lightPos);
    tanLightPos = normalize(tanLightPos);

    ecReflectVec = reflect(-tanLightPos, tanPerturbedNormal);

    float Ratio = F + (1.0 - F) * pow((1.0 - dot(-i, n)), FresnelPower);
    vec3 reflectColor = vec3(textureCube(EnvMap, ecReflectVec));

    gl_FragColor = vec4(reflectColor, 1.0);

}
```

Comment: This looks pretty bump mappy to me. Could you put in the heightmap/normalmap used? Also did you check by flipping gl_FrontFacing ?

Comment: @mrVoid, By "heightmap/normalmap" what do you mean? There are no normal map images if thats what you mean. I am supposed to use code to do that. I believe its supposed to be `vec3 n = normalize(vec3(p.x, p.y, 1.0));` part. Also the radius of the tube is given by `TubeRadius`

Comment: I did my comment too hastily. Thats and interesting problem, will look into it.

Comment: Hows the problem going? Could you give a wire-frame shot for the geometry?